# I cannot download application from TFS -- erroneously shows "All files are up to date"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to download an application to my local repository. After mapping it to my TFS folder I click on get latest, which produces an erroneous "All files have been downloaded" message. No files are downloaded. I have attempted re-mapping it to my repo and I have tried getting a specific version with bother "Overwrite" boxes checked. That didn't work.

I have previously had this application downloaded, but I deleted it because I was having other TFS issues with it (that was while back and I don't recall what they were).

Comment: when you remap, check the folder to see whether it has hidden files .vs , delete it may help.

Comment: Another thing to try, is to perform an Undo Pending Changes. I suppose that after deleting all files locally, TFS has registered this intent. When performing a get-operation, it will merge those changes with your local workspace. Since you deleted everything that action is repeated.

Comment: Patrick, yes it's still an issue; none of the below solutions work.

Answer (score 2):

- Right-click the project in Source Control Explorer
- Click Advanced -> Get Specific Version
- Leave "Latest Version" alone (or chose it in the Type dropdown if it's not chosen)
- Check the two "overwrite" check boxes
- Press Get

Sometimes your workspace gets messed up.  If this doesn't fix the issue, the next step is to remap everything and I'll let someone else describes that.

Comment: Like I said in the description, I have already done both of these things. They do not fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried remapping it to another folder (not sure if that's what you mean by "remapping it to my repo")? The next step is to create a new workspace; which is a PITA

Answer (score 2):

Try to create another Workspace and get latest the files there:

- From the File menu, select Source Control, and then click Workspaces.
- In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click Add.
- Type a descriptive name in the Name box, enter a comment describing the new workspace in the Comment box, and provide alternative Owner and Computer name values, as necessary.
- Under Working Folders, in the Source Control Folder box, click the text box and then the ellipsis (…).
- In the Browse for Folder dialog box, select a server folder, and then click OK.
- Under Working Folders, in the Local Folder box, click the text box, and then click the ellipsis (…).
- In the Browse for Folder dialog box, select a folder on your computer, and then click OK.
- In the Add Workspace dialog box, click OK to create the workspace.
- In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click Close.

After you created the new Workspace, go to the "Source Control" section of a project in the "Team Explorer" tab.

Once you're in the source control view, you can right click any folder in source control, right click on it, and click "Get Latest Version".

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you first try to run the **tf get command** to pull down files in command line. If nothing changed and you still get the same info.

Then you could try to below work around to make the item in Source Control Explorer gray out again by getting specific changeset 1.

1. Open team explorer
2. Click Source Control
3. Right click on you file/folder
4. Select **Advanced** Click on Get specific Version
5. Choose Changeset Type and enter 1

[image]

The item in Source Control Explorer will gray out again. This is due to:

> Changeset 1 is a special changeset on your Team Foundation Server
>   instance. It was created as part of the setup routine and only
>   contains one thing - the root node ($/) in your source control tree.
>   If you do a get for Changeset 1 on any actual files then they will not
>   exist at that point in time on the system so will be deleted locally
>   and the server will know this.

***Note:*** This will change the status of your files to "Not downloaded" and will **remove the local copy of the file**. It will only remove files that were put there by TFS.

After this, try to get latest for your code again, which may do the trick.

If all of above not work, suggest you simply delete the old workspace and create a totally new one, then map with server path, download files.

Comment: Neither resetting to changest 1 nor removing old workspace and adding a new one fixed this issue. I should add that the solution I can't download is not on the disk -- I deleted it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right click on `file/folder` > `Source Control` > `check-out for edit`

Now you can take the latest.

Answer (score 0):

If all other solutions do not solved your problem you can try this:
Go to your Organization's Settings. Under 'Users' tab you will see all the users who'll have accress rights. All users should have the same access rights.